# Понимание Task.WhenAll, код ведет себя не очевидным образом

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, task

Проблема следующая представьте что у нас вызовы `GetTask` и `GetOtherTask` являются долгими по времени, что бы ускорить время ожидания мы их объединяем и вызываем через `Task.WhenAll`, но проблема в том что вызов `GetTask` вызывается не 2 раза (по количеству элементов в коллекции что видно в коде) а целых 5, и как результат у нас происходит лишних 3 вызова.

```cs
namespace Example {
    class Program {
        static async Task Main(string[] args) {
            var firstTask = GetOtherTask();

            var secondTasks = Enumerable.Range(0,2).Select( async x=> {
                return await GetTask(); /// <--- Сюда заходит 5 раз хотя должен только 2
            });

            var tasks = secondTasks.Union(new[] { firstTask });
            await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

            var result = tasks.Select(x => {
                return x;
            }).ToArray();

        }

        static async Task<int> GetTask() {
            await Task.Delay(100);
            return 0;
        }

        static async Task<int> GetOtherTask() {
            await Task.Delay(100);
            return 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: А если после Union добавить ToList или ToArray?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov ваш совет помог, спасибо, но что там происходит внутри вот вопрос?)

Comment: Попробуйте вместо `var` указывать явный класс, тогда скорее всего и не нужно было бы ToList или ToArray добавлять.

Comment: Повторить 5 заходов - не получилось, ровно два раза по два

Comment: да про пять я загнул было 4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема заключается в ленивости.

`tasks` - это на самом деле итератор.

1. Первый раз он материализуется при передаче в `Task.WhenAll`
2. Второй раз - при вызове `.ToArray` после `.Select`

Чтобы этого избежать, достаточно материализовать его один раз перед передачей в `Task.WhenAll` и передавать уже результат.

---

Также можно сразу материализовать `var secondTasks = (...).ToArray()`

---

Альтернативным решением может стать использование значения возвращаемого методом `Task.WhenAll` - массив значений переданных тасков:

```
var tasks = secondTasks.Union(new[] { firstTask });
var taskResults = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

var result = taskResults.Select(x => {
    return x;
}).ToArray();
```

В этом случае возможно не нужна последняя строчка с `result`.